# Job execution cluster with prioritization and cancel/retry

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, aws-batch

Usecase:- "We have varied execution time(millisecond,seconds, minutes, hours) requests to process. We want to design a cluster which can process these requestes from SQS. We also want in-built features in cluster like cancel/retry, priority based execution. We explored AWS batch which provide most of these features but it starts new container for each request we will have delayed response for quick execution time requests"

We are also exploring if AWS batch or any other cloud provider provides warmup container feature like lambda remains warm for 15 min along with priority execution, auto scaling, cancel/retry feature

We have tried AWS batch but it slow short execution time jobs and impacts client delivery SLAs. We are also exploring EKS with AWS batch, but seem there steep learning curve with EKS.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch is tuned for jobs that run greater than a few minutes. I would use some other workflow or task system that is able to dispatch different jobs to different resources, one of those being AWS Batch. The milliseconds and seconds tasks can either be handled by running microservice agents, or AWS Lambda.

I wrote a blog post about how to [scale Celery workers with Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/hpc/run-celery-workers-for-compute-intensive-tasks-with-aws-batch/), but the same architecture would work for other background task queues such as BullMQ, etc. Note, I did not cover how to handle requests in the shorter runtime SQS queues with other services.

Comment: Thanks Angel, I am also looking to use a broker which sends to shorter runtime jobs to ECS-Fargate and longer ones to AWS Batch. I also went through your blog,  I hv couple of questions there, do we need to have unmanaged CE so that we can scale as per messages in SQS, does celery workers read messages from SQS directly, if yes, it means we cant use AWS batch priority-queue/cancel-clone features for each message.

Comment: Blog post assumes managed CEs, but an unmanaged would also work, though you lose out on the resource scaling that Batch offers. Once a worker starts it pulls from the SQS queue directly. If you were looking at sending long runtime tasks as a single Batch request, I would skip the whole CW + EB setup and just call Batch from the celery worker and monitor the job from that small process.

Comment: The above would require code changes to the worker, the blog was specifically "i cannot change the celery code, but I can route tasks to the appropriate service to run the worker."